# CSS inherit not inheriting

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Basically, here's my issue. The container thisone is not inheriting the height of renderzone properly. It just stays the same and it's really aggravating. Renderzone will grow dynamically with user content, and I'd like there to be a column for the chapter-list-thing so it doesn't end up wrapping the content.

JSFiddle version - http://jsfiddle.net/K2NPz/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="hidden"
             style="visibility: visible; height: auto; ">
            <div style="height: auto;">
                <div id="renderzone" 
                     style="background-color: #bbe4e0; padding: 5px;">
                    <div style=" min-height: 175px;height: inherit;float: left;overflow: auto;height: 100%;">
                        <div id="chapterlist" 
                             style="float: left; width: auto; height: auto; display: inline-block; border: 1px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 0px; min-height: 140px; min-width: 150px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: #B9D9F1;">
                            <a href="#render1" 
                               style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; color: #346460; font-size: 130%;" 
                               id="anchor1">Header 1</a><br>
                        </div>
                        <img src="blank.jpg" alt="White Pixel">
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color: white; border-radius: 10px; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; margin-right: 20px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;">
                        <h1 id="render1" 
                            name="render1" 
                            class="renderh1">Header 1<br></h1>
                        <p id="render2" 
                           name="render2"
                           class="renderp">Long text here...<br>
                        </p>
                        <img id="render3" 
                             name="render3" 
                             class="renderimg" 
                             alt="Blank Pixel" 
                             src="" 
                             style="max-width: 400px;"><br>
                        <a href="#top">To Top</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="??" id="sender">
            <input type="button" value="??" id="modoru">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cringe at the sight of that horizontal scrollbar. What's more, using my browser's find function, I can't find any occurrence of the `inherit` keyword in your CSS at all.

Comment: I think OP is try to keep the content in an autoflow, which is not achieved, because of the `float` assignments.

Comment: Sorry for all the inline styles. It's for an html email generator thingy, so I have to use those in-place of an external stylesheet unfortunately. Also, my code has now been edited.

Comment: The new html your just included doesn't make it easier to find your problem. Try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem, so people can check what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure what a jsFiddle is, really. I think I did it right though... http://jsfiddle.net/K2NPz/1/

Comment: Make sure you're keeping an eye out for compatibility: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Eh... I'm mostly worried about gmail, outlook, and Thunderbird - all of which display things more or less okay. Further compatibility can be worked in later once the base is done.

Comment: Can you create an image of what it is supposed to look like and of what you are seeing?

Comment: If you think it'd help? http://postimage.org/image/1zjcktz2c/ - left is current, right is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your style to `overflow:auto`. Because you are floating it, it gets out of the scope. Placing it with overflow will return it in the scope.

Comment: Whether an element is floating or not doesn't change its ability to inherit properties from its parent element.

Comment: True, but OP is talking about auto-stretch to the size of the content. As you can see from the style properties, there is no actual height property to inherit.

Comment: I just made the overflow edit and it works WITHOUT the doctype, but with the doctype it fails for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your doctype needs a bit more information than just `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I'm not so good with doctypes, but you need to tell what doctype to use, not only html. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: I'm using the HTML5 Doctype, which is just <!DOCTYPE html> oddly enough. The problem persists with XHTML 1.0 Strict's Doctype though, I've already tried.

Comment: Applying `overflow:auto;` to the container element, as suggested, worked for me. In my case I had a left floated element and a right floated element at the end of (but within) my container element that were not inheriting the background image/color until setting the overflow of the container element to automatic. Thanks for the fix Marnix.

Comment: @BoltClock - What then, according to your understanding, caused the problem described in my previous comment, if not the floating of the contained elements?

Comment: @DominorNovus: Do you have a test case I can look at?

Comment: @BoltClock - Here's a page under development, soon to go live: http://tinyurl.com/8cnqys3 - Find `#standard_page_wrap` and disable `overflow: auto;` (currently applied to element). Result: `#writeyourown_final_container` no longer inherits the background-image.  The problem _apparently_ occurred once I applied the floats though I'm open to whatever you can deduce as the problem.

Comment: @DominorNovus: Ah, that's the because `overflow: auto` causes the container to stretch to fit its floats, which is basically the same issue encountered. However it is not an issue of inheritance, which in CSS is an entirely different concept.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks. I now understand the distinction you're making. The problem is the stretching of the container and thus its background which is nothing whatsoever to do with the inheritance of the contained floated elements. In fact, the contained floated elements were inheriting nothing of pertinence to their backgrounds in the first place. Instead of writing "no longer inherits the background-image", I should have wrote "no longer has the background of the container element behind it".

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements have problems with inherit heights, because they don't know the height of the centre content.

**The worst method :**  clear the floaters after the last child element by insert div (you can use also span instead of div `<span class="clear"></span>` ).

```css
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
}
.floated {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Better way:** - `overflow: hidden` for the parent div.

If you use floats child elements you need to clear his parent div. It will make the margins work proper and don't generate the messy html elements.

```css
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden 
}
.floated {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div class="floated"></div>
</div>
```